# Android Studio Dolphin new logcat change fontsize?

Tags: android-studio-3.1

Android Studio Dolphin got a new logcat. It looks promising, but I haven't found any way to change the new logcat font size not changing the editor font size.

In previous versions of Android Studio logcat was following to the console style and it was possible to reduce the font size with Setting->Editor->Color Scheme->Console Font but not anymore.

Is there any way to change the new logcat font size not changing the editor font size?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just zoom in or zoom out in the logcat it change the font size

Comment: It works! Confirmed.
Don't forget to enable "Change font size with Ctrl+Wheel" in Settings -> Editor->General